# How particles at CERN age compared to observer?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

I'm just curious how significant is the difference in aging of particles at CERN versus the people observing them. If one second passes for a particle at CERN from it's point of reference going at 99.9999991% of the speed of light, how many seconds, hours, days or years pass for the observer sitting at CERN?  Any suggestion for the right formula to calculate this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will ignore the fact that the particle is traveling in a circle.

The Lorentz factor is

$$\gamma = \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} \approx 23600$$

That means we see the particle age $23600$ times slower than it would at rest. We see its length contracted by a factor of 23600 in the direction of travel. A sphere would become a thin pancake.

The particle sees the same thing when looking at us. It us moving at $99.99999991%$ c. It sees our clocks running 23600 times slower, and us forshortened.

From the particle's point of view. 1 second passes on our slow clocks in the time it takes for 23600 seconds on the particle's clock.

From our point of view, 23600 seconds pass on our clocks while we wait for 1 sec to pass on the particle's slow clock.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - that's really interesting and helpful.  So essentially we see that during our approximately 6.55hours only one second passes at the particle's clock and the particle sees that in it's 6.5 hours only 1 second happens at our clock.  Now let's consider that CERN is a circle and let's assume that it's of a size that the particle would be at precisely the same spot each second. How would it work from this perspective with the clocks? At least from conceptual point of view.  Would the clocks be in sync each second?